# Batch file renaming

Tags: batch-file

i come with a little problem :'( :
I  have many txt files and get more and more by day and i need to make  a back-up of them and encrypt them for safety reasons so i made a batch script :

```
@echo off 
FOR /R d:\txtwork %%G in (**.txt **.trt) DO (
certutil -f -encode "%%G" "%%G.bak"
echo. >>D:\txtwork\logs\logbak1.txt %time:~0,-6% - Made a back-up of file - "%%G" 
)
```

Ok this works perfectly but I want to make a batch to decode them as well and change the extension into the old one (from .txt.bak or .trt.bak to .txt or .trt ) so I tried and made this :

```
@echo off 
FOR /R d:\txtwork %%G in (**.bak) DO (
certutil -f decode "%%G" "%%G:~0,-4" 
)
```

BUT IT DIDN T WORK SO I TRIED

```
@echo off 
FOR /R d:\txtwork %%G in (**.bak) DO (
set var_1="%%G" 
certutil -f decode "%var_1%" "%var_1:~0,-4%" 
)
```

It didn't work either.
Help ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: *It didn't work* is not a useful problem description. In what **specific way** is it *not working*? If you want us to help you, you have to **clearly** and **specifically** explain the problem you're having, and **ask an actual question**. *It didn't work either. Help?* is not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `"%%G:~0,-4"` is totally wrong;
- to retrieve value of `var_1` variable you need to enable [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and use `!var_1!` instead of `%var_1%` although doing that would bring another problem:

  - `certutil -f decode "!var_1!" "!var_1:~0,-4!"` would expand to
  - `certutil -f decode ""something.txt.bak"" ""something.txt""` (note doubled double quotes);
- use next `set` command syntax: `set "var_1=%%G"` (note the first double quote position).

Next code snippet should work:

```
@echo off 
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /R d:\txtwork %%G in (**.bak) DO (
    set "var_1=%%G"
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    certutil -f decode "!var_1!" "!var_1:~0,-4!" 
    ENDLOCAL
)
```

However, you could use [Parameter Extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) as follows:

```
@echo off 
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
FOR /R d:\txtwork %%G in (**.bak) DO (
    certutil -f decode "%%G" "%%~dpnG" 
)
```